# Context is null at onMapReady callback

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an Android App.
In my App I'm calling a map fragment right after an ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent is dispatched in the MainActivity.

The map fragment snippet is:

```html
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
.
.
.
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mMapView = mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }
.
.
.
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }
```

If I don't dispatch the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent the fragment works as planned, however, when dispatching the intent the context in MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity()) is null

I think I need to better sync the the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent completion and the onMapReady method but not sure how.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: try to write MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity()); before this  mMapView.onCreate(null); and instead of passing null pass savedInstanceState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this,

```
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            mMapView = mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
           //initialize before calling map onCreate
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
            if (mMapView != null) {
                //instead of passing null its a good practice to use savedInstanceState
                mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                mMapView.onResume();
                mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
            }
        }
```